# UIWebView over an UIView gets UIView alpha value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview

I'm developing an iOS 4 application.

I have a main view that contains another `UIView`, named `shadowView`, with an `UIWebView` inside. This `shadowView` has black as background color and alpha = 0.3f.

My problem is that `UIWebView` inherits `shadowView` alpha value, and I don't want that, I need UIWebView has alpha = 1.0.

Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have added a `UIWebView` to a `UIView` which has an alpha of 0.3.

On iOS, any sub-views inherit their parent views alpha values (or rather, the parent view 'masks' the sub-view).

It sounds as if you want your `shadowView` to have a translucent background: rather than setting the alpha of the view, you should instead do this:

```
[shadowView setAlpha:1.0];
[shadowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3]];`
```

...which will (as long as your view isn't set to be opaque) give you a nice translucent background and allow your sub-views to not appear transparent as well.

Comment: Yes, you have understood it my question. Thanks, it works perfectly.